# Can I ask for help to name my thesis?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, titles

I am finishing my undergraduate thesis, now my advisor has asked me to think of a name, but since in my work I use a mathematical tool to deal with two somewhat distant elements, I cannot think of a suitable name to unify my topics to be dealt with, the names that come to mind are long and I would like something more concrete.

I'm not thinking of copying a title, but I think I could use some "brainstorming" so I can come up with an appropriate title.  Is this a valid question?

Comment: You can ask, but it is likely to be downvoted and closed. So, I would recommend finding a different place to talk with people about it. Reddit? Twitter? Your thesis supervisor?

Comment: Maybe through the chat rooms?

Comment: A problem is that such a question does not have a clear "correct" answer. Therefore the question is unlikely to survive long in main. Chatrooms are an option, but the number of eyes you get on your question will be lower there. If you can find a topical chatroom that would be nice. I'm not very optimistic about you finding help here. Yes, we are likely to have people with the required expertise, but the question does not really fit. We have other types of questions with similar problems (like book recommendations). They suffer from similar problems, when votes reflect only popularity.

Comment: (cont'd) But I really want to commend you for asking before posting. Props.

Comment: As a resource you might consider the *tag names* for Math.SE, as these are of necessity somewhat short and to the point.

Comment: Have you asked for suggestions from your advisor, or talked with?  If not, that's to whom you should focus this question.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  My advisor only asked me to think of a name, my intention is to already have a good proposal for the title.

Comment: Do your best to formulate a title you think might work; but don't expect yourself to have a "perfect title".  I agree that proposing a title you've that you've thought carefully about, to your advisor, is a good call.  But as an advisor to you, he will appreciate your effort, and may be happy with the title, or discuss it with you, to point out a possible refinement, Luis.  It can be a win-win situation!  I'm with @Jyrki on this, on your having asked prior to posting!

Answer (score 15):

Such a question would be off-topic on the main site.

I can see such a question being closed as "opinion-based", since it would fall under the category of "chatty, open-ended questions" mentioned in "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" as a class of questions that should be avoided.

It could also be closed for being "not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)": in particular, see the section titled "What to ask here" in the last link.

You could take your question to one of the chatrooms associated to this site. Perhaps the main chatroom "[Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics)" would be optimal, should you choose to take this option.